# Creating fields in MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, sqlite

I would like to change my database from SQLite to MongoDB since mongo is schema less. In SQL database i had to create multiple rows for each attribute for the same sku(a product). I have to create n number of columns since each attribute have different specifications. Now in mongo I am planning to create only one document(row) for a sku having same id. To achieve this I would like to create a field(column) for specifications like html, pdf, description, etc. Now the last field is for attributes which has different values. I would like to store it in hash.(key value pairs). Does it make sense to store all the attributes in single cell? Am I going in right direction? Someone please suggest.

EDIT: 
I want something like this.

[image: sample file]

My question is, in SQL i was creating columns for each attributes like attribute 1 name, value and attribute 2 name, value. This extends the row size. Now i want to store all the attributes in hash format(as shown in the image) since MongoDB is schema less. Is it possible? And does it makes sense? Is there any better option out?

Comment: it will be great if you could attach sugested document schema

Comment: Please take the time to show us your SQL schema and your proposed Mongo schema. Then we are in a better position to help - remember we don't know your project like you do.

Comment: @Hughzi Thank you.. Yeah and please give me some time. I will show you.

Comment: @profesor79. Please give me some time. I will show my schema

Comment: please look at my edit

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, how you store the data should be influenced by how you intend on accessing or updating the data, but one approach would be to create an embedded attributes object within each sku/product with all attributes for that sku/product:

Based on your example:

```
{
    "sku_id" : 14628109,
    "product_name" : "TE Connectivity",
    "attributes" : {
        "Widhth" : [ "4", "mm" ],
        "Height" : [ "56", "cm" ],
        "Strain_Relief_Body_Orientation" : "straight",
        "Minimum_Operating_Temperature" : [ "40" , "C" ]
    }
},
{
    "sku_id" : 14628110,
    "product_name" : "Tuning Holder",
    "attributes" : {
        "Widhth" : [ "7", "mm" ],
        "diametr" : [ "78", "cm" ],
        "Strain_Relief_Body_Orientation" : "straight",
        "Minimum_Operating_Temperature" : [ "4" , "C" ]
    }
},
{
    "sku_id" : 14628111,
    "product_name" : "Facing Holder",
    "attributes" : {
        "size" : [ "56", "nos" ],
        "Height" : [ "89", "cm" ],
        "Strain_Relief_Body_Orientation" : "straight",
        "Minimum_Operating_Temperature" : [ "56" , "C" ]
    }
}
```